# Using vector shapes from FLASH PRO in FLASH BUILDER (Shapes/Graphic Symbol -> SWC?)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder

How to use simple vector shapes from FLASH PRO in FLASH BUILDER?

I'm already using SWC method to export buttons and movieclips, but i cant find a way to export simple shape assets. I've converted them to Symbol-Graphic, but it does not work. I've tried to convert them to button/movieclip changing base class to shape, but it generates compilation errors :(.

I don't want to use hundrets of movieclips just to export simple icons for FLASH Builder (memory usage would be huge), **is there any solution for exporting simple shapes to SWC and use them in FLEX?**

Edit: I'm using CC versions.

Answer (score 0):

If thosse desired shapes are simple, the best method would be to generate them with actionscript code. Just create  custom classes whitch extends Shape class and then you can import them from compiled swc file or straight from included folder. 
Maybe this can hel you too: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838144/is-there-a-way-to-convert-a-shape-created-in-flash-to-actionscript-2-code)